# Android drawing

Tags: java, android, graphics

I am following a tutorial, and have the following code, but I want to modify it a little bit, so I want when its clicked inside the circle it must be filled with another collor, how I can do it, as I am just learning this concept I dont have any idea of how it can be done :/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(new MyView(this));
     }

     public class MyView extends View {
         public MyView(Context context) {
              super(context);
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a touch listener on your view

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View myView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(myView);

        myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();

                //if(x==... your code here

                invalidate(); //this repaints the view
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```